# stripping the << tag for c++ in php

Tags: php

I want to keep `<<` tag in string but because of strip_tags, it is also removed from string.

```
$str = "#include<iostream> using namespace std;int main () {  int a, b=3;  a = b;         a-=10;  cout<< a;  return 0;  }";

$newtext = htmlspecialchars((strip_tags(($str),'<iostream>,<')));

echo "<br>" . $newtext;
```

Output:

```
-#include<iostream> using namespace std;int main () { int a, b=3; a = b; a-=10; cout
```

Suggest me solution.

Comment: Why are you using both `strip_tags()` *and* `htmlspecialchars()`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to strip_tags() if you're using htmlspecialchars(). The latter function will make the string safe for output on your page, including embedded tag-like sequences.

Comment: Hey thanks...n now its working correctly actually there was </br> tag also in the string n i want to remove it bt at d same time i want <iostream> and << but i got my solution thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the tags and sava << the you can use preg_replace

```
$str = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '' $str);
```

Comment: that will remove `<iostream>` also

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily replace it with something else

```
$newtext = htmlspecialchars(str_replace('[[[[', '<<', strip_tags(str_replace('<<', '[[[[', $str),'<iostream>,<')));
```